# R: The system cannot find the file specified?

Tags: r, error-handling

Just an hour before I installed a package `ISLR`. From that time I'm getting an error message every 30secs.

> The system cannot find the file specified!

I tried changing the working directory, still its not solved. I'm spending all my time to close this error message! plz help..

Comment: What command produces this error?

Comment: No commands. Its coming automatically every 20-30 sec intervals or less! Edit:: especially when I type something in.

Comment: If you restart R and don't load anything, do you still get the message?

Comment: I tried it., same prob still persist :p

Comment: This is probably an intermittent RStudio bug.  Restart RStudio.  See https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/questions/200649466-The-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified

Comment: I restarted R-s several times, but didn't help. Restarted System and tried again. the bug came again. Now re-installed and working properly. Thanks a lot guys.. :)

Comment: likely duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32982167/rstudio-project-cannot-find-the-file-specified-on-r-session-restart

Answer (score 8):

I had the same. For some reason he cannot find the file anymore and every time he tries to auto save he fails. I did a save as but that didn't work either. I finally copied all my progress somewhere else (notepad file) and restarted. I removed the file that was causing the problem and created a new one with the same name where I pasted my progress. This solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, so I reload the page and opened a new file.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is restarting R
Go to Session > Restart R or Ctrl + Shift +F10