# R command to navigate to a folder in Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio

Is there a function to navigate to a specific folder ? (the equivalent of clicking the 3 dots button and nivigate to it).

I usually put the folder as working directory and click on go to working directory. I am looking for a direct command, and without being forced to set it as working directory.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should create RStudio projects and get all the files there, so you won't need to set a working directory:

[Create Projects in RStudio](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200526207-Using-Projects)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I quitted using the project approach because it keeps giving me an error while editing the scripts (because the project is on dropbox).

Comment: What error were you getting, that shouldn't be a problem?

Comment: Hello and thanks for your answer. I have putted the error in a comment below.

Answer (score 0):

While working inside a project that is saved on dropbox or onedrive the following error keeps appearing. Something like (word by word translation) : The process cannot access the file because the file is used by another process.

[image]

Comment: [See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37820998/rstudio-and-google-drive-syncing-problems-the-process-cannot-access-the-file-b)

Comment: Thanks for this link. I found this post on Rstudio's website too: [link](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200534477-Using-Dropbox-with-RStudio-Projects)