# RStudio and Google Drive syncing problems: Mark II

Tags: r, google-drive-api, rstudio

There is an enormous amount this on the web (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37820998/rstudio-and-google-drive-syncing-problems-the-process-cannot-access-the-file-b) and [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/mostly-resolved-dropbox-box-sync-google-drive-etc/6098/8) and [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/the-process-cannot-access-the-file-because-it-is-being-used-by-another-process/4719)) but no clear solution. So this question may be a duplicate but there was no solution for the older versions.

I was just wondering if anyone has found a way to resolve this extremely annoying problem of the conflicts between the autosave functions in RStudio and Google Drive resulting in an error message 'the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process' interrupting your work every 5-10 seconds.

I recently bought a windows PC after years of reading PCs were better for running RStudio than a mac, but **what a blunder that was**. No such problems on the Mac OS.

Google drive is great and cheap but I would not have a huge problem with changing to a different cloud storage provider, but, from what I gather it's not just Google Drive but *any* cloud-based storage software that has this same incompatibility with RStudio.

I find it incomprehensible that this is a problem windows users who use R just have to live with.

So **has anyone solved this problem?** and if not, **how do you work in RStudio and save your work without going crazy?!!??**

Really I would *love* to know.

Comment: I think there is no 1 correct solution for this which will work in all cases. There are solutions in the 1st link you shared which worked for few people https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37820998/rstudio-and-google-drive-syncing-problems-the-process-cannot-access-the-file-b Did you try them all and none worked?

Comment: I'm curious about your claim that you've read "PCs were better for running RStudio".  The main difference I'm aware of is that Windows has huge problems with encodings which don't exist on Macs.  Can you add a link to one of those claims that Windows RStudio is better in some other way?

Comment: @user2554330 I shouldn't have said 'read' more 'heard'. I have made an extremely costly mistake.

Comment: @Ronak Shah I tried all the methods except yours, which I didn't understand (my fault not yours).

Comment: Also am dying to know how people work in RStudio and sync to Drive easily. Surely there must be a way right?